# POST not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had a loginform previously which looked like following

```
<div class="span-10 last">
    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginActionUrl" />
    <user:login   actionNameKey="login.login" action="${loginActionUrl}"/>
</div>
```

but now i changed the form to looks like following.

```
<div class="span-10 last">
    <c:url value="/login/loginNow" var="loginActionUrl" />
    <user:login actionNameKey="login.login" action="${loginActionUrl}"/>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this now

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginPageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginNow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(
        @RequestHeader(value = "referer", required = false) final String referer,
        @Valid final LoginForm loginForm, final BindingResult bindingResult,
        final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws CMSItemNotFoundException {

        if (somethingMissing) {
            return to login page.
        }

        return FORWARD_PREFIX + "/j_spring_security_check";

    }
}
```

But now i am getting Request method post not supported. I don't know why..? How can i rectify the mistake..
Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed your JSP is calling the correct controller method? Use FF firebug (or equiv) to look at the URL the page is hitting. Does it work if you change the method to accept a GET and test the URL by itself? Lastly if you're using tomcat try deleting the work directory and restarting tomcat - sometimes it keeps old versions of class files in there which results in strange behaviour.

Comment: Yes i have put log lines ..i am confirmed it goes to correct controller. What i got from this url is you have put <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> in your <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> for forwarding it from your controller.But now it's forwarding to j_spring_security_check from controller but somehow the form objects are lost in forwarding technique so i come again on the login page even if the credentials are correct. So i am just model.addAttribute(loginForm); before forwarding it to j_spring_security_check. I am testing it now

Comment: I am not sure should i do request.setAttribute("j_username",form.getUsername()) something like that before forwarding it to j_spring_security_check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put this on web.xml

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```